# Does simulating chiral gauge theories lie within BQP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, quantum-computing, quantum-information, physics

In theoretical physics, there is a branch of quantum field theory dealing with chiral gauge theories. It has been conjectured by Feynman [1] and others that all quantum field theories can be simulated in a limit computable manner efficiently on a quantum computer. However, there is the challenge of finding an efficient limit computable simulation of chiral gauge theories on a quantum computer. Does this problem lie within $\mathsf{BQP}$?

[1] Richard P. Feynman. [Simulating Physics with Computers](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~christos/classics/Feynman.pdf). International 
Journal of Theoretical Physics, Vol. 21, Nos. 6/7, 1982

Comment: Since this is a computer science theory forum, it would be nice if you could clarify (or provide references explaninig) why simulating *chiral* theories (in which sense, btw?) should be "harder" in terms of computational complexity.

Comment: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32977/how-do-you-simulate-chiral-gauge-theories-on-a-computer/33001#33001 is this question relevant?